# Linux file association

Tags: linux, command-line

With a desktop environment, there are file associations that goes with it.

I'm a minimalistic user, who doesn't use any of such, but still want some kind of file associations to ease my burden.

So I'm searching for a program that does something like the following.

`open file.pdf`

this will look at the extension, and translate to `okular file.pdf`.

Of course one can always write a bash script to do this. I wonder if there is something existing, so I don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You want `xdg-open` for this.​

Answer (score 1):

You can use gnome-open for ubuntu / gnome.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `zsh`

```
# Suffix aliases (Type a file as a command and this program will launch)        
alias -s jpg=gthumb
alias -s png=gthumb
alias -s pdf=okular
alias -s html=firefox
alias -s ogg=mplayer
```

In your example you would just type `file.pdf` and okular would start